# Change from cloud JSON to local JSON

Tags: android, json, local

I'm looking at making a change in an app I'm working on (it's based off of this: http://goo.gl/rDBXVl) from loading a cloud based resource to a local based resource. I'm not particularly sure how I would go about doing this. I want to go from pulling a JSON file off the internet to pulling the JSON from my Assets folder.

I located the area in the app where it pulls the URL and loads the JSON but am unsure of what changes to make at this point.

```
public void loadData (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Check Network State
    if (!NetworkUtil.getNetworkState(this)) {
        final RetryFragment fragment = RetryFragment.getFragmentWithMessage("No connection");
        this.addFragment(fragment, RetryFragment.TAG, true);
        return;
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null || savedInstanceState.get(KEY_LIST_DATA) == null) {
        final String url = super.getResources().getString(R.string.config_wallpaper_manifest_url);
        if (url != null && URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            // Add Loading Fragment
            final LoadingFragment fragment = new LoadingFragment();
            this.addFragment(fragment, LoadingFragment.TAG, true);

            // Load Data
            final RestClientHandler handler = new RestClientHandler(this);
            RestClient.get(this, url, handler);
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Restored Instance");
        this.mData = (ArrayList<NodeCategory>) savedInstanceState.get(KEY_LIST_DATA);
        this.mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_LIST_POSITION);
        if (this.mPosition != -1) {
            mIgnoreSelection = true;
        }

        this.configureActionBar();
    }
}
```

Comment: RestClient.get(this, url, handler); 
replace that with a code that would load a file from assets

Answer (score 0):

You have another option,

just save json in sharedpreferences. so easily read and write it.

Save sharedpreferences code bellow.

```
    /**
 * write SharedPreferences
 * @param context
 * @param name, name of preferences
 * @param value, value of preferences 
 */
public static void writePreferences(Context context,String name,String value)
{
    SharedPreferences setting= context.getSharedPreferences("Give_your_filename", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=setting.edit();
    editor.putString(name, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```